# ESXi Not Booting from USB

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant, syslinux

I hope you can help, because I'm stumped.

I've got an old HP DL385 G2 server. I have successfully installed VMWare ESXi 6.0 to an old 16GB Corsair Voyager flash drive.

Because I didn't like the USB hanging off the server, I figured I'd utilise the internal port, and would get a physically smaller USB drive to do so.

As such, I got myself a 16GB Sandisk Cruzer Fit. I went through the exact same install process as before. The install completes successfully. Upon reboot however, I get an error

```
SYSLINUX 3.86 EBIOS load error
```

I did some research, and found that it may be as a result of the USB not working so well with GPT partitioning. So, as per the recommendations found whilst researching, I booted the installer with the boot option 'formatwithmbr' so as to use MBR rather than GPT partitioning. Again, the installer completes successfully, but I'm greeted with the same wonderful error.

I'm about ready to toss the drive - is there anything else that somebody may suggest?

EDIT: I have tested the Corsair Voyager on the internal port which works successfully, and the Cruzer will not work on either.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I'm sorry. The Voyager works on both internal and external USB ports. The Cruzer will not work on either.

Answer (score 1):

have you compared the USB disk identifier on both to see WHICH FAT32 or NTFS each version is using?  this is often a drive format error - there are a about 20 different FAT32 formats , and quite a few NTFS - GRUB has problems with some of them